# I am trying to print a random word from a text file but when I get this error that there is No such file or directory

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static char words[540000][25];
    FILE *file;
    int i, j;
    size_t cnt, n;
    char word[25];

    srand(time(NULL));
    file = fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Projects/RWord.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("The file cannot be opened.\n");
        perror(file);
        return 1;{}
    }
    cnt = 0;
    while(1==fscanf(file, "%24s", word)){
        if(cnt == 540000)
            break;
        strcpy(words[cnt++], word);
    }
    fclose(file);
    n = cnt;
    if(n > RAND_MAX){
        int part;
        size_t random = 0;
        i = n / RAND_MAX;
        part = rand() % (i+1);
        if(part == i){
            j = n % RAND_MAX;
            if(j != 0)
                random = random + RAND_MAX*part + rand() % j;
            else
                random = random + RAND_MAX*(part-1) + rand();
        } else {
            random = random + RAND_MAX*part + rand();
        }
        printf("%s\n", words[random]);
    } else {
        int random = rand() % n;
        printf("%s\n", words[random]);
    }
    return 0;
     
}
```

Note: It is a bit weird but I am trying this code on mobile.
I am getting this error: No such file or directory.
I used `perror()` and got the specific error. I want to print a random word from the text file but I can't get the code to read the f

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means the path you provide is wrong...

Comment: Error isn't lying. Are you sure something is at that *absolute* path?

Comment: `perror(file);` isn't right: `file` may be a `NULL`  pointer but is the wrong type.

Comment: Are you sure the code you run is the code you compiled? Start changing `perror(file)` to `perror("The file cannot be opened.\n")` and drop `printf("The file cannot be opened.\n");`. Did you get any warnings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well its that I want to print a random word from a text file but when I run this code it gives error: No such file or directory. But I have checked the absolute path and there is a text file named RWord.txt.